# What is the result of this infinite sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to find the value of $\mathbf S$ where

$$\mathbf S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{k}; k \in \mathbb N, x \in \mathbb R^*, x \not \in \mathbb N$$

I had a look to WA which lead me to [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(sin(2*pi*k*x)%2Fk),%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity).

I think this result can be simplified. So I did some research and *some* hours later, I found this result:

$$\mathbf S = \pi (x+\frac{1}{2}-(2n+m)) ; n,m \in \mathbb N$$

I'm not satisfied with this result either. I think I miss something on the way.

I'm stuck. What is the result of this infinite sum?

Comment: This is the Fourier series of $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \pi x$ on $[0,1]$, see e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374221/fourier-series-of-fx-x). An expression for the sum of the series that holds for all $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$ is $\frac{\pi}{2} - \pi \{x\}$ where $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$ is the fractional part of $x$

Comment: It seems that wolfram alpha doesn't understand the Fourier series so well.. I wonder how it could be improved for detecting and simplifying such Fourier series.

Comment: Try writing down the Taylor series of $-\log(1-z)$ at $z=0$, replacing $z$ with $e^{2\pi i x}$ and taking the imaginary part.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : but you can't replace $|z| < 1$ by $e^{i t}$ directly, you have to prove also that $\sum_k z^k/k$ converges on $|z|=1, z \ne 1$, and that it is equal to $\lim_{r \to 1^-} \sum_k r^k z^k/k$

Comment: @user1952009: you are clearly right, one has to be quite careful when acting on the boundary of the pointwise-convergence disk, but Abel's lemma is designed just for that.

Comment: An alternative is to compute $\sum \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)e^{-\lambda n}}{n}$ in a similar way, then apply Dirichlet's test and the dominated convergence theorem in letting $\lambda\to 0$, that is the usual method for computing the continuous analogue $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : if Abel's lemma means [summation by part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) then it is exactly what I wrote on the [other post on the functional equation for $\zeta(s)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770480/the-theory-of-riemann-zeta-function-titchmarsh-page-15-question-in-the-proof-of), so I approve :).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : but I don't see the dominated convergence as is, I think you'll have to use summation (or integration) by parts too.

Comment: @user1952009: oh, sure, we have to apply Abel's lemma (summation by parts) even in that case, I agree.

Comment: Correction: my comment above is slightly misleading. The series is not the standard Fourier series of $\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi x$ but rather what you get by naively adding the Fourier series of $-\pi x$ (the sawtooth) with the Fourier series of $\frac{\pi}{2}[2\theta(x)-1]$ (the square wave) on $(0,1)$. Also: the formua I gave above only holds for $x>0$ for $x<0$ the constant term should be $-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, WA missed some simplification.

$$\log(1-e^{i2\pi x})-\log(1-e^{-i2\pi x})=\log\left(\frac{1-\cos(2\pi x)+i\sin(2\pi x)}{1-\cos(2\pi x)-i\sin(2\pi x)}\right)\\
=\log\left(\frac{2\sin^2(\pi x)-i2\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}{2\sin^2(\pi x)+i2\cos(\pi x)\sin(\pi x)}\right)=\log\left(-\frac{ie^{i\pi x}}{ie^{-i\pi x}}\right)=i2\pi x+i(2k+1)\pi.$$

So with the factor $\frac i2$ the sum should be

$$\pi\left(k+\frac12\right)-\pi x$$ where $k$ is indeterminate.

---

As the sine is periodic so is the Fourier series, and the indeterminate $k$ must be some integer offset from the integer part of $x$,

$$\pi\left(\lfloor x\rfloor+n+\frac12\right)-\pi x.$$

Then we can evaluate the series at $x=\frac12$, which is an ordinary point ($x=0$ wouldn't work), get $S(\frac12)=0$, and conclude

$$S(x)=\pi\left(\frac12-\{x\}\right).$$

[image]