# Riemann zeta function functional equation proof explanation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

In Riemann zeta function functional equation proof I arrived to a following equation
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}2\right) \zeta(s)}{\pi^{\frac{s}2}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^{\frac{s}2-1}e^{-n^{2}\pi x}dx,$$
where $s\in \mathbb{C}$ and Re$(s)>1$. Next step is to prove that 
$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}2\right) \zeta(s)}{\pi^{\frac{s}2}}=\int_0^\infty x^{\frac{s}2-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^{2}\pi x}dx.$$

Why exactly can we change the order of integration and summation? I'm having trouble with this equation, since $s\in \mathbb{C}$. What exactly should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For inverting $\sum$ and $ \int$ from scratch the method is always the same ([see this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770480/the-theory-of-riemann-zeta-function-titchmarsh-page-15-question-in-the-proof-of/1772037#1772037)), adapted to your problem it gives :

- use that for $x >0$  $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} < \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{- \pi n x} = \frac{e^{-\pi N x}}{1-e^{-\pi x}}$$

  so that for $Re(s) > 1$ : $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \left|\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=N}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx\right| < \lim_{N \to \infty}  \int_0^\infty |x^{s/2-1}| \frac{e^{-\pi N x}}{1-e^{-\pi x}} dx  = 0$$
- then using that $\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx =n^{-s} \int_0^\infty y^{s/2-1} e^{- \pi y} dy$ we get that 
  $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty  \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx  = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty n^{-s} \int_0^\infty y^{s/2-1} e^{-\pi  y} dy 
   = 0$$
- finally $$\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx = \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=1}^N e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx + \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx$$ $$ = \sum_{n=1}^N\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1}  e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx + \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx  $$
  $$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1}  e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx -  \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1}  e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx + \int_0^\infty x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty e^{- \pi n^2 x} dx$$
  and let $N \to \infty$

Comment: One potential problem: when $s=2$, your upper bound becomes $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\pi \cdot N x}}{1-e^{-\pi x}} \cdot dx $$ and this integral does NOT converge (according to wolfram).

Comment: I believe what is said is correct if the lower bound of $0$ is replaced with $1$. Perhaps what needs to be done is bound $|\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{s/2-1}\sum_{n = N}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^{2} x} dx|$ from above by the technique mentioned and then use another technique to bound $\int_{0}^{1} x^{s/2-1} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} e^{-\pi n^{2} x} \cdot dx$ from above. Perhaps by using another bound for $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} e^{-\pi \cdot n^{2} x}$. Any thoughts on this?